# How do you apply a different object-fit properties to an HTML's video poster independently than it's parent video?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

This can easily be achieved by using event handlers and javascript. I am looking for the CSS solution.

In the following example, applying styles to one overrides the other:

```css
video {
  object-fit: cover;
}

video[poster] {
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <video width="600" height="100" poster="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" controls>
   <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I doubt you can, the poster is part of the video element

Answer (score 0):

`video[poster]` isn't a selector for the poster, instead it matches a `video` element that has a `poster` attribute.

I don't think you could target the video's poster separately. You could have a separate element with the poster image over the video element before playback instead.